# Why does this CSS transition only work when used as a function instead of a component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have a simple sidebar where I use transitions for opening/closing the sidebar.
The transitions work when I call my `Sidebar` component as a function *(sidebar 1 in example)*. 
The transitions **don't** work when I use the `Sidebar` component as a component *(sidebar 2 in example)*.

Why don't they work in example 2?

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const [sidebarCollapsed, setSidebarCollapsed] = React.useState(false);

  const Sidebar = ({ bg, ...props }) => {
    const width = sidebarCollapsed ? "0px" : "200px";

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: bg,
          height: "100px",
          width: width,
          transitionDuration: "500ms"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {/* Sidebar 1 -> function */}
        {Sidebar({ bg: "blue" })}

        {/* Sidebar 2 -> component */}
        <Sidebar bg="red" />

        <button onClick={() => setSidebarCollapsed(!sidebarCollapsed)}>
          Toggle sidebar
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how the React DOM is working, if you want to animate it, you have to pass the prop of the open. When you are trying to pass a *state* from one component to another, you should always do it throught the props.

```js
 const Sidebar = ({ bg, open, ...props }) => {
    const width = open  ? "0px" : "200px";

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: bg,
          height: "100px",
          width: width,
          transitionDuration: "500ms"
        }}
      />
    );
  };
const App = (props) => {
  const [sidebarCollapsed, setSidebarCollapsed] = React.useState(false);



  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {/* Sidebar 1 -> function */}
        {Sidebar({ bg: "blue", open: sidebarCollapsed })}

        {/* Sidebar 2 -> component */}
        <Sidebar bg="red" open={sidebarCollapsed}/>

        <button onClick={() => setSidebarCollapsed(!sidebarCollapsed)}>
          Toggle sidebar
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```